How to make a button with static position inside ModalBottomSheet?
I have a structure like that:
Scaffold -> Box -> ModalBottomSheet -> Some content stuff + Button
The idea is that when I open ModalBottomSheet both in half and full state, my Button stays in the same place - at the bottom of BottomSheet (like on the pic below).
However, I have zero ideas on how to do it. If I place a button inside a nested Box, it obviously doesn't stand still, but rolls around with it. Please help me with how I should implement this.
Fun code:
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun BottomSheetExample() {
    val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()
    val sheetState = rememberModalBottomSheetState(
        initialValue = ModalBottomSheetValue.Hidden
    )
    val openSheet = remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

    Scaffold { paddingValues ->
        Box(modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .padding(paddingValues),
            contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
        ) {
            Button(onClick = { openSheet.value = true }) {
                Text(text = "Open Bottom Sheet")
            }

            if (openSheet.value) {
                ModalBottomSheet(
                    onDismissRequest = { openSheet.value = false },
                    shape = SquircleShape(32.dp, 32.dp, 0.dp, 0.dp, cornerSmoothing = CornerSmoothing.Medium),
                    containerColor = Color.White,
                    content = {
                        Box(
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .heightIn(min = 0.dp, max = LocalConfiguration.current.screenHeightDp.dp - 90.dp
                                )
                                .fillMaxSize()
                                .padding(16.dp)
                                .background(Color.LightGray)
                        ) {
                            Text(
                                modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.TopCenter),
                                text = "This is the bottom sheet")
                        }
                    }
                )
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun rememberModalBottomSheetState(
    initialValue: ModalBottomSheetValue
) = remember {
    ModalBottomSheetState(initialValue = initialValue)
}

data class ModalBottomSheetState(
    val initialValue: ModalBottomSheetValue
)

enum class ModalBottomSheetValue {
    Hidden, Expanded
}


Is the idea for the button to be inside the bottom sheet, or not so?  Also, have you considered placing the button after the bottom sheet declaration?

Well, you wouldn't be able to get the bottom sheet  to be under the bottom. but theoretically, if we got the height of the bottom sheet, the visible height of it using .onGloballyPositioned {                                     visibleSheetSize = it.boundsInWindow().height.dp                                 } on the modifier, and finally the button height. then subtract them from each other we would get the offset, then we will create a new button inside the bottom sheet and set that y-offset to it, it would work. assuming that the button is at the bottom of the screen as in the photo.

According to the above issuetracker, there is no implementation for this use case yet, if you try to change the offset of the button relatively to the BottomSheet's offset that won't work either, simply because the BottomSheet api does not expose the offset..
issue url:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/209825720?pli=1
